# Read system console on iOS using private api

Tags: ios, iphone-privateapi

Is there a way to read a system console using some private API (on iOS device itself)?

I saw this article (and many questions) which reference it:
http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/03/accessing-the-ios-system-log/

However, the described approach doesn't work for quite long time already. It returns only logs which are written by application itself and not by system services and other apps.

**Usual disclaimer:** This is for research only. It won't be distributed to AppStore, so I don't care that it won't be accepted to it.

Comment: with private API the main problem is: you will be not noticed when not available. Can be even a minor version iOS upgrade make all your effort value to 0. Are you really sure want to do that? :) nothing better to research?

Comment: @matheszabi: yes. I am sure I want to do this

Comment: the first result in google: http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/03/accessing-the-ios-system-log/ but  Iam sure you will find 100 and maybe 1 is working. I wouldn't waste more than 10 min on this and in general in private API hacking

Comment: Don't know exactly how to do it but here is a few good places to start: 1. syslogd is probably receives log messages from all of the processes https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/syslogd.8.html 2. Try reading from /dev/console and /dev/tty.

Comment: I suffered the same problem now.Post your solution if you have found the answer please.  Thank you~